# Docker Compose Setup in Windows 10 for nginx php-fpm fails with Error

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have below docker composer file which seems to be loading and working fine for phpmyadmin on 8080. however i cant get the app working for the php ? i get a error called.

**403 Forbidden**

**FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.99.1, server: 192.168.99.100, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1",**

docker yml file

```
nginx:
    build: ./nginx/
    ports:
        - 80:80
    links:
        - php
    volumes_from:
        - app

php:
    build: ./php/
    expose:
        - 9000
    links:
        - mysql
    volumes_from:
        - app

app:
    image: php:7.0-fpm
    volumes:
        - ./:/var/www/html
    command: "true"

mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes_from:
        - data
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: secret
        MYSQL_DATABASE: project
        MYSQL_USER: project
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: project

data:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
        - /var/lib/mysql
    command: "true"

phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
    ports:
        - 8080:80
    links:
        - mysql
    environment:
        PMA_HOST: mysql
```

Folder Structure is as below.
[image]

Comment: You cannot mount folders outside your user home folder to Docker on Windows.

Comment: Yes it worked when i move the projects folder to the windows user directory , next queston is there no way to mount a directory in D: ? with docker ? is it impossible ?

Comment: It is possible but involves extra steps, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/33404132/4190526