# fopen does not create files when used with docker

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile

Code of Dockerfile is here

```
FROM php:7.0-cli
COPY ./ /
```

Code of create.php is here

```
<?php
$fp = fopen($argv[1],'wa+');
fwrite($fp,'sample');
fclose($fp);
?>
```

I build my docker using following command in debian - stretch

```
docker build -t create-tool .
```

I run it using following command in debian - stretch

```
docker run create-tool php create.php /home/user1/Desktop/test
```

But it is not creating the file, instead it throws the error **"failed to open stream"**.

Comment: You are trying to pass in a file location on your host OS. Docker containers can only access file paths within the running container (unless you bind mount them)

Comment: Do you have all necessary permissions?

Comment: I have logged in as root

Comment: @JRLambert can you tell me how can I mount them? please.

Comment: Mounting in a Docker file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-host-directory-in-docker-container

Comment: @Neodan What permissions are required and where can they be given?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `touch()`? It can solve your problem!

---

http://php.net/manual/en/function.touch.php

Answer (score 0):

3 Scenarios I would investigate :

1. Because `/home/user1/Desktop/test` doesn't exist **within** the docker container. That file exists on your `host` system, so it's out of reach for the `container`.

   If you want to access files on your `host`, you'll need to share the folders you want the `container` to access with a `volume`.
2. The path exists in your container, but is for example a directory. You can check quickly if a file exists and/or is accessible within your `container` by running `docker run create-tool ls -lsah /home/user1/Desktop/test`.

   This will then list what the container can access with the given path.
3. Double-check what the value of `$argv[1]` in your PHP script is. You wouldn't want to get escaped characters, etc. `print_r($argv);` should help.