# Development Docker container to work on without dep. locally installed

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm wondering if it's possible to create some kind of docker container that will allow me and my friends to develop directly into container - without having node or it's dependency installed locally? Is it possible to develop like that and use git as well?

If it's possible, could you share a link where I could check how to do it with node apps?

Thanks!

Comment: you can mount your local directory  contains code to container. you can look at this (question)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-host-directory-in-docker-container]

Answer (score 0):

You can build your image by installing all dependencies (`node, npm, your packages`) then copy your code inside and share your working directory, your `entrypoint/cmd` should run your node script.

Read [this article](http://bitjudo.com/blog/2014/03/13/building-efficient-dockerfiles-node-dot-js/) which will help you understand how to build efficient `dockerfile` for `node.js` especially. You can also read this from docker's website for [general best practices](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/eng-image/dockerfile_best-practices/).

Here is a simple docker file to only give you a **simple idea** how to hookup your code and run simple html page in your machine inside nginx server inside container (you did not install nginx at all in your machine).

**Note**: this is only to understand the concept

1) Create a new file, name it `dockerfile` and add the following content, I tried to give you comments for each line to understand but you can remove those comments if you want.

```
FROM ubuntu #this is the base image
MAINTAINER Your name
RUN apt-get update #feel free to install and update packages 
RUN apt-get install -y nginx #easily as you're in your linux env, you can install nodejs here 
COPY . /usr/share/nginx/html/ #share the current content of working directory to nginx folder inside container
ENTRYPOINT [“/usr/sbin/nginx”,”-g”,”daemon off;”] #run nginx server that should display copied files 
EXPOSE 80 #expose port 80 to your machine (host)
```

Notice `COPY` where we copied content of your code inside container.

2) Inside the same directory, add index.html and your content inside it

```
$ echo "hello world" > index.html
```

3) Build your image and tag/name it `MyImage`

```
docker build -t MyImage:latest .
```

4) Run your container or instance of your image:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 MyImage
```

5) browse http://localhost

For more info. and details, better to check [docker's documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/).