# Write dataframe to Teradata in Databricks

Tags: databricks, teradata-sql-assistant

I am writing df data into one of Teradata table then i am getting below error. I am able to read the data just getting error for writing.
I am not getting why same driver is working for writing the dataframe.

```py
df=spark.sql("""select * from tbl_name""")
config_dict={"JDBCURL":"jdbc:teradata//${jdbcHostname}/database=${jdbcDatabase}","JDBCDriver":"com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver","DB_User":"dbc","DB_PWD":"dbc"}
jdbcUrl=config_dict["JDBCURL"]
jdbcDriver =config_dict["JDBCDriver"]
user=config_dict["DB_User"]
password=config_dict["DB_PWD"]
df=spark.sql("""select * from testing""")
df.write.format("jdbc") \
      .mode("overwrite") \
      .option("url", jdbcUrl) \
      .option("dbtable","database.tbl_name") \
      .option("user", user) \
      .option("password",password) \
      .save()
```

error:>> java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

can someone help me on it.

I tried to connect teradata manually then i am able to connect with same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install JDBC driver for Teradata before running the code. You can do it by attaching the Teradata JDBC driver as library to your cluster:

- using the [Maven coordinates](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.teradata.jdbc/terajdbc).
- if it's already downloaded,  you can put the file to DBFS and refer the library by its DBFS path

See [docs](https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html) for instructions on working with libraries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the driver as pointed out and then specify driver class name as an option. `driver="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver"` below.

```py
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder
                    .appName("Teradata connect")
                    .getOrCreate()
df = spark.read
          .format("jdbc")
          .options(url="jdbc:teradata://xy/",
                   driver="com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver",
                   dbtable="dbname.tablename",
                   user="user1",password="***")
          .load()
```

For driver installation see:

- [How to add jdbc drivers to classpath when using PySpark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925864/how-to-add-jdbc-drivers-to-classpath-when-using-pyspark)
- https://docs.databricks.com/libraries/index.html

Comment: You will probably also need STRICT_NAMES=OFF option since pyspark passes its own options to the driver.