# How to mount host data to different containers

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I need to mount host directory `/data` to 6 containers `h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6`

**`/data` is an external hard disk mounted on the host. The 6 containers can be opened and closed easily.**

The 6 containers will go into their own sub-directories of `/data` to analyze data independently and produce new data locally. All sub-directories have nothing to do with each other.

A relevant question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-host-directory-in-docker-container), but no preferred answer is given.

How to do that? Below are the containers and images I have now.

`$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
d9bd9334a1e7        ubuntu              "/usr/bin/bash"     19 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             h6
23679fe7252b        ubuntu              "/usr/bin/bash"     19 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             h5
e2864e38e746        ubuntu              "/usr/bin/bash"     19 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             h4
c8996a304638        ubuntu              "/usr/bin/bash"     19 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             h3
9acd2a223d86        ubuntu              "/usr/bin/bash"     19 hours ago        Up 18 hours                             h2
5690b8c7b6da        ubuntu              "/usr/bin/bash"     2 days ago          Up 12 hours                             h1`

`$ docker images 
REPOSITORY              TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
docker.io/hello-world   latest              f2a91732366c        2 months ago        1.85 kB
docker.io/ubuntu        27                  422dc563ca32        2 months ago        252 MB
docker.io/ubuntu        latest              422dc563ca32        2 months ago        252 MB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IF those containers are *already* running, you cannot easily add /data to them.
Except maybe with [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/).

But the best practice remains either:

- make images with /data already in it (Dockerfile ADD)
- or use the existing image and launch your container, but with the -v (volume) option. See **[Use volumes](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/volumes/)**.

[image: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/images/types-of-mounts-volume.png]

Comment: I added a bold sentence in the post.

Comment: It does not change my answer

Comment: The last method is the best choice for me. It seems I should use `docker run -t -i -v /home/test --name test itbilu/test /bin/bash` , but how to specify names of containers?

Comment: @questionhang docker run is for launching a *new* container, not for modifying an existing running one.

Comment: @questionhang You can specify the name of the new container you are launching with -name: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#container-identification

Comment: I do not understand `docker run -t -i -v /home/test --name test itbilu/test /bin/bash`.  Whose name? What is the container that will be generated? What is itbilu/test? BTW, there is no easy way to add `data` to known containers, like `h1 and h2`?

Comment: @questionhang That is what my all answer is saying: "there is no easy way to add data to known containers, like h1 and h2": you can try docker cp, but again, that is not the best practice

Comment: `docker run -t -i -v /home/test --name test itbilu/test /bin/bash` would run a container named `test`, based on the image `itbilu/test`, but overriding its `CMD` with a `/bin/bash` process: as long as that bash remains opened, the container will run.

Comment: That command will generate a directory with the same path in the new container, but the directory is empty.

Comment: @questionhang yes, you need to specify the path on the host machine that you want to mount: https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/volumes/bind-mounts/#choosing-the--v-or-mount-flag. `-v /data:/home/test`