# How access the Odoo source code in Odoo docker container image?

Tags: python, odoo

I have set the Odoo docker container in my local machine and I am able to run the Odoo server. But I want to create custom modules. How do I access the Odoo   source code inside the container image and make some changes?

Comment: Mount a [volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/)!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: insted of mounting can't i update the odoo code which is there in the odoo image ?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can build a docker image for yourself. If you want to add your module into Odoo image and don't want to mount it in your command line or write it into docker-compose file.

It's mean that you need to create your docker image.

- Create Dockerfile like this: https://github.com/odoo/docker/tree/master/11.0
- With this code, you can create directory and mount it into your image.

  `RUN mkdir -p /mnt/extra-addons \
      && chown -R odoo /mnt/extra-addons
  VOLUME ["/var/lib/odoo", "/mnt/extra-addons"]`

FYI: This is tutorial to create image: https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/baseimages/

Hope it will help you.