# `mount: permission denied` on Azure virtual machine running Docker

Tags: azure, docker, mount

I created a Data Science Virtual Machine on Azure and a storage account (like I would a virtual machine). Then I followed [these directions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-create-file-share) to create a file share. A blade "Connect" appears at the right with the command to connect from a Linux computer:

> To connect to this file share from a Linux computer, run this command:
>
> `sudo mount -t cifs //storagename.file.core.windows.net/filesharename [mount point] -o vers=3.0,username=storagename,password=[GUID],dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp`

I start a Docker container with

```bash
sudo docker run -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3 bash
```

create a directory, replace `[mount point]` with it, and I get a permission error, and with sudo I get missing executable:

```
root@9cda7bc6176d:~# mkdir /mnt/storage
root@9cda7bc6176d:~# mount -t cifs //storagename.file.core.windows.net/filesharename /mnt/storage -o vers=3.0,username=storagename,password=[GUID],dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp
mount: permission denied
root@9cda7bc6176d:~# sudo mount -t cifs //storagename.file.core.windows.net/filesharename /mnt/storage -o vers=3.0,username=storagename,password=[GUID],dir_mode=0777,file_mode=0777,sec=ntlmssp
bash: sudo: command not found
```

How can I mount an Azure file share inside a Docker container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need the file share to be on Azure? Because Docker can mount a filesystem and you don't have to manage an additional storage account. From [this Stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container), this command:

```
sudo docker run -v ~:/mnt/caller -it tensorflow/tensorflow:latest-py3 bash
```

will put you in a Docker container with the host home directory mounted at `/mnt/caller`.