# Docker volume and mapping of host folder

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows

This might be too general question, unfortunately I was not able to find the right answer. I would like to dockerize my aspn.net mvc application. I have method that scans local folder for files

`C:\input_data`

The path is passed to a method and everything works great.

When you create an image and container you will have to map this directory as volume

`docker run -v c:/input_data:/data`

I understand that inside the container you can use only `/data`. How `/data` will be passed to the method as a valid folder path? In addition the path is stored in settings table, so `C:\input_data` will be passed to a method all the time and this method would expect `C:\input_data` as a valid path.

How is this resolved? Do I have to provide instructions to docker how to resolve this mapping between `/data` and `C:\input_data`?

Thanks

Comment: Which image are you using? Can you add your Dockerfile to the question?

Comment: Sorry, I did not create Dockerfile yet. I'm just trying to wrap my head around this internal working of Docker/container. I understand that Dockerfile contains the mapping to host folder and alias that we would like to use internally.

Comment: I will use Microsoft .net core image

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)

Comment: Don't agree. This is not duplicate. The post you mentioned is about mapping volume. In this case how do you pass mapped host folder to a method? You can pass /data as input folder to a method. Settings table has folder path defined by a user. Unless Docker somehow magically resolves host folder -> /data -> C:\input_data. It looks like something is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can set an environment variable on Dockerfile to set the path to `/data`.

`ENV METHOD_PATH="/data"`

And change your configuration to use the env `METHOD_PATH`

Doing this, your app will always use the path `/data` inside the Docker

In this link you can find more info in how to use environment variables with ASP.NET:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2