# Docker Bindmounting a Volume not working as expected

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I need access to data (logs and cached files) from my docker containers, and so I am following instructions in this article on bindmounting volumes.

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-the-docker-container-and-the-host

I have created the `~/appdata/example-app/logs` directory on the server and started a container with the following command.

```
$ docker run -d -v ~/appdata/example-app/logs:/logs --restart always -p 81:80 path-to-docker-image-repo
```

But no logs are being output to the server directory.

I run the following command to inspect the files within the container:

```
$ docker exec -t -i example-app /bin/bash
```

I can see that my log file does indeed exist in the container (and have also verified that the app is running as expected). Note that this app is an ASP.NET Core app. I'm not sure if that is relevant, possibly because the path structure may be different for ASP.NET core apps?

```
logs\2019-06-14.log.json
```

I don't understand why I'm not seeing the files in the `~/appdata/example-app/logs` directory.

Also, I actually want two directories mounted to the server, an additional directroy for cached images as well as logs, if this is possible?

Comment: try just "appdata/example-app/logs:/logs   (removed ~/)

Comment: Could it be that docker daemon is not allowed to write to this directory? Can you try changing the ownership or access rights of the logs folder on your host machine just to check?
I've witnessed weird behaviour from docker when it comes to mounting volumes without proper permissions

Comment: Abhishek DK - I tried your suggestion but it did not work

Comment: Kārlis Ābele - do you know how you would go about changing the changing the ownership or access rights for the docker daemon? Thanks

Comment: I have also reviewed this document https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container, where there is reference to using absolute paths, but this has not worked and is in conflict with the documentation also.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `~/appdata/example-app/logs`, try using `$PWD/appdata/example-app/logs`

Comment: No luck here either