# Docker container does not run when using --mount flag

Tags: node.js, docker, volume

I just want to create a docker container that pulls from the official Node.js image using the guidelines [found here](https://nodejs.org/de/docs/guides/nodejs-docker-webapp/).

The only change I want to make is I would like to mount my host directory to my container so that I can create new files on the host and have them update in the container.

I have tried every suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container): -v flag, --mount flag etc.

But when I use these flags with the run command, no container actually runs.

I run the following:

```
docker run -p 49160:8080 -d myname/node-web-app --mount source=/Users/myname/desktop/dockyard/enviro
```

It spits out a container ID:

```
7302055670c231fb41d04d6475d42405cbee834e37e0827a68d7c396a918d3ec
```

But when I run `docker-ps` the container list is empty.

When i check `docker-ps -a` I can see that it was exited with code 9:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                         PORTS                    NAMES
dbf7973608a0        myname/node-web-app            "docker-entrypoint.s…"   4 seconds ago       Exited (9) 2 seconds ago                                quirky_sammet
```

I have searched for an explanation of code 9, and I cannot find anything.

Would really appreciate any help that can be provided.

***UPDATE***

Tried: 
`docker run -p 49160:8080 -d myimage -v /Users/myname/desktop/dockyard/enviro:/usr/src/main`

Container exits with code 0. `docker logs` simply returns `v11.15.0`

I understand that this means the container is exiting because of no process, BUT if i run `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d myimage` without the -v flag, container runs perfectly fine.

So not sure why -v flag would cause exit (0).

Dockerfile as per Node.js tutorial:

```
FROM node:11

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/main

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: can you provide the container logs ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find it easier to `docker run --interactive --tty` than `docker run --detach` while you're debugging.

I think your `mount` syntax is borked. I think you need the `source` and the `target` otherwise Docker Engine does not know where to map the directory within the container.

I'm less familiar with the `--mount` syntax so please try the following to map your local directory (`/Users/myname/desktop/dockyard/enviro`) to the container's directory (`/Users/myname`)

```
--volume=/Users/myname/desktop/dockyard/enviro:/Users/myname
```

When containers exit, you should be able to pull logs using, e.g.:

```
docker logs dbf7973608a0
```

#### Update

What you provided *should* work; it does for me.

I create a simple Express server on `:8080` and map in a host directory to the container.

Created index.js:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 8080

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Happy Birthday Freddie!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

And package.json:

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./index.js"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~4.17.1"
    }
}
```

Then built|ran it:

```sh
docker build --tag=56822320 .
docker run \
--interactive \
--tty \
--publish=8080:8080 \
--volume=${PWD}:/test \
56822320
```

And it works:

```sh
curl localhost:8080
Happy Birthday Freddie!
```

To prove that the mapping is working:

```sh
docker run \
--interactive \
--tty \
--publish=8080:8080 \
--volume=${PWD}:/test \
56822320 /bin/sh
# ls /test
Dockerfile  index.js  package.json
```

HTH!

Comment: Thanks for response. Tried `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d myimage -v /Users/myname/desktop/dockyard/enviro:/usr/src/main` and now exiting with code 0. Logs simply return `v11.15.0`. If I run `docker run -p 49160:8080 -d myimage` it works fine. So not sure why the volume flag would exit code 0.

Comment: Please add more details to your question and I'll try to repro this. IIUC you'll need to run some Node.JS process to keep the container running. Exit code 0 is a completion without error. Perhaps that's what's missing? Your Dockerfile would be insightful.

Comment: so that worked thank u very much. ill try to figure out what exactly was the difference between the two. One thing I noticed: if i use  `--volume=${PWD}:/usr/src/main` instead of `--volume=${PWD}:/test` it throws `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`. why would express be available to one path and not the other?

Comment: You're welcome! In your example you have `WORKDIR /usr/src/main` and then `COPY package*.json ./`. The `./` in that copy refers to the `WORKDIR` set previously i.e. `/usr/src/main`. The `${PWD}` in the `--volume` map your current directory to `/usr/src/main` too. So there's likely some redundancy in there. It's good practice to not attempt to copy packages into the container but to have the container do the `npm install`.