# External application.properties file to a spring boot app in a docker container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, deployment

I packaged a Spring boot app with its own application.properties file as a docker image. I will like whoever runs the image to provide his/her own property files (overriding the one inside the app) when running a container off the image.
My Dockerfile looks like this.

```
# our base build image
FROM maven:3.6.2-jdk-11 as maven

WORKDIR /app

# copy the Project Object Model file
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml

# fetch all dependencies
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# copy your other files
COPY ./src ./src

# build for release
# NOTE: my-project-* should be replaced with the proper prefix
RUN mvn package -Dmaven.test.skip=true && cp target/myApp.jar app.jar


# smaller, final base image
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
# OPTIONAL: copy dependencies so the thin jar won't need to re-download them
# COPY --from=maven /root/.m2 /root/.m2

# set deployment directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy over the built artifact from the maven image
COPY --from=maven /app/app.jar ./app.jar

# set the startup command to run your binary
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar"]
```

I run the image as follows.

```
      docker run -p 8085:8085 docker-spring-boot-name
```

How do I use an external application properties.
I have read similar answers, but I seem to not to understand, although, I don't think I have a unique issue.?

Comment: you have to give the docker container access to the host file system by mounting the folders.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)