# How do I open a repository that is cloned inside a Docker container through Visual Studio Code in Windows 10?

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code

I have a Docker container where I have cloned a project repository. I have Visual Studio Code installed in my Windows 10 OS. Now I can't access the repository as it is inside the container and not in my local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount the volume on your host system.

You can achieve this within your **Dockerfile**, with the **Docker run command** or with **Docker-compose**

[This should answer your question sufficiently.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)