# log4j2 logs for Spring boot application inside Docker container

Tags: spring-boot, docker, log4j2

I have a spring boot application which uses log4j2 to write logs. When I deploy this application to a Docker container, I want the logs to be written to a file at a specified location outside the container. How can I do this ? I tried providing the path of the log folder using an environment variable on startup but its of no use. No logs are being written. Please help

Answer (score 0):

You have to mount the directory on the host file system inside the container. A simple web search will yield many results on how to do this such as [How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)