# sh: can't open 'run.dev.sh': No such file or directory with declaring volumes in `docker-compose.yml`?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, mounted-volumes

I face [this exact error](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/6916/44677) but Idk how to solve it. Idk if my Windows firewall is blocking it & if it is, then how would I solve it? for context, I'm not using docker desktop. just docker with wsl2 on Windows 11.

I'm dockerizing a remix app in node.js.

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  redis:
    image: redis:7.2.4-alpine
    container_name: aff_redis_dev
    env_file:
      - ../../.env.development
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    command: redis-server --save 60 1 --loglevel warning --requirepass 123456abc
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "redis-cli", "ping"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 30s
      retries: 50
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/data
  web:
    image: affiliates:0.0.1
    build:
      context: ../../
      dockerfile: docker/development/Dockerfile
    container_name: aff_dev
    env_file:
      - ../../.env.development
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
      - 8002:8002
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
      - ../../data:/data
    restart: unless-stopped
    depends_on:
      redis:
        condition: service_healthy
volumes:
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

#### Dockerfile

```bash
FROM node:20-alpine AS base

# mostly inspired from https://github.com/BretFisher/node-docker-good-defaults/blob/main/Dockerfile & https://github.com/remix-run/example-trellix/blob/main/Dockerfile

# Check https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine to understand why libc6-compat might be needed.
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN corepack enable && corepack prepare pnpm@8.15.4 --activate 
# set the store dir to a folder that is not in the project
RUN pnpm config set store-dir ~/.pnpm-store
RUN pnpm fetch

# 1. Install all dependencies including dev dependencies
FROM base AS deps
# Root user is implicit so you don't have to actually specify it. From https://stackoverflow.com/a/45553149/6141587
# USER root
USER node
# WORKDIR now sets correct permissions if you set USER first so `USER node` has permissions on `/app` directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY --chown=node:node package.json pnpm-lock.yaml* ./
COPY --chown=node:node /app/drizzle/migrations ./migrations

RUN pnpm install --frozen-lockfile --prefer-offline

# 2. Start the development server
# Inspired by https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/36935
RUN mkdir -p /app/.cache && chown -R node:node /app/.cache
# Persist the remix cache in a volume
VOLUME ["/app/.cache"]
# COPY --from=deps --chown=node:node /app/node_modules ./node_modules
COPY --chown=node:node . .

# This will do the trick, use the corresponding env file for each environment.
COPY --chown=node:node .env.development .env.development

# Copied from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69867550/6141587
USER root
# Give /data directory correct permissions otherwise WAL mode won't work. It means you can't have 2 users writing to the database at the same time without this line as *.sqlite-wal & *.sqlite-shm are automatically created & deleted when *.sqlite is busy.
RUN mkdir -p /data && chown -R node:node /data

USER node
EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000
ENV HOSTNAME 0.0.0.0
ENV NODE_ENV development

COPY --chown=node:node public ./public

# Move the drizzle directory to the runtime image
COPY --chown=node:node /app/drizzle/migrations ./migrations
COPY --chown=node:node scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs ./scripts/drizzle-migrate.mjs
COPY --chown=node:node scripts/package.json ./scripts/package.json
COPY --chown=node:node scripts/pnpm-lock.yaml ./scripts/pnpm-lock.yaml
COPY --chown=node:node scripts/run.dev.sh ./run.dev.sh
RUN chmod +x run.dev.sh

CMD ["sh", "run.dev.sh"]
```

#### run.dev.sh

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Set the directory of the database in a variable
DB_PATH=/data/affiliates.dev.sqlite

# Set to true only when you want to run the migrate script, i.e when changing database schema
# Automate it by only setting it to true by tracking `entries.idx` in `migrations/meta/_journal.json`
MIGRATE_DATABASE=false

# Inspired by https://pranavmalvawala.com/run-script-only-on-first-start-up & https://serverfault.com/a/1134812/1078165
FIRST_TIME_MIGRATION_DEV="FIRST_TIME_MIGRATION_DEV"
if [[ ! -e /data/$FIRST_TIME_MIGRATION_DEV ]] || [[ $MIGRATE_DATABASE = true ]]; then
    # Place your script that you only want to run on the first startup.
  echo 'Initialize database first time only'
    touch /data/$FIRST_TIME_MIGRATION_DEV

    echo "Migrating database '/data/affiliates.dev.sqlite'"
    pnpm db:migrate:dev & PID=$!
    # Wait for migration to finish
    wait $PID
fi

echo "Starting development server..."
pnpm dev
```

if I remove the volumes mapping `- ./:/app` from `docker-compose.yml`, then everything works fine.

but if i add it, i get this error:

> sh: can't open 'run.dev.sh': No such file or directory

as said in the other answer, i tried this command:

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd):/app" busybox ls -l /app
```

i got this:

```bash
Unable to find image 'busybox:latest' locally
latest: Pulling from library/busybox
7b2699543f22: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:650fd573e056b679a5110a70aabeb01e26b76e545ec4b9c70a9523f2dfaf18c6
Status: Downloaded newer image for busybox:latest
total 293
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000          1432 Mar 10 10:53 Makefile
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            13 Jan 21 06:43 README.md
drwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           512 Jan 24 05:42 app
drwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           512 Jan 25 16:23 build
drwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           512 Mar 10 09:30 data
drwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           512 Mar  9 13:11 docker
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           265 Jan 25 06:22 drizzle.config.ts
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            80 Mar 10 14:17 env.d.ts
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           324 Feb 28 07:21 litestream.yml
drwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           512 Mar 11 07:27 node_modules
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000          2574 Mar 11 07:27 package.json
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000        289002 Mar 11 07:27 pnpm-lock.yaml
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000            80 Mar 11 07:26 postcss.config.mjs
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           247 Mar 10 10:36 prettier.config.cjs
drwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           512 Jan 25 16:23 public
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           156 Mar 10 11:56 remix.config.cjs
drwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           512 Mar 10 12:10 scripts
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           171 Jan 19 09:18 tailwind.config.ts
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           585 Mar 10 14:18 tsconfig.json
-rwxrwxrwx    1 1000     1000           450 Mar 11 07:20 vite.config.ts
```

i understood that the error meant that it didn't find `run.dev.sh` in the top-most directory on my host side but i don't know how to solve the error?

i tried `$pwd`, `$(pwd)`, `$(PWD)`, `${PWD}` & many other variations. finally, settled on `./:/app` as it is the provided solution [here](https://devops.stackexchange.com/a/9004/44677) that works cross-platform.

how do I solve this?

the reason I'm mapping the current directory is that I want hmr/live-reloading to work with remix.

but I have to use docker as I need Redis which isn't directly available in Windows. of course, I can just start a Redis server but I'd like to use Docker to control it all.

Answer (score 1):

You get this error because your volume configuration overwrites whatever you have in that path with the contents of your `.` directory, including the script that you add with this `COPY --chown=node:node scripts/run.dev.sh ./run.dev.sh` (and earlier you had `WORKDIR /app` so this goes there).

It's an either-or situation and you need to decide. *Either* you copy something to the `/app` folder during the docker image building *or* you mount them during the container start.

Currently your container seems to be configured much more in a style that expects no mount overriding, since you create a separate user to the image and all, which - while a good practice for production - might mess up the permissions anyway for live reloading.

So your only option (if you want live reload) is to remove basically everything from the dockerfile that adds anything to `/app`, and if those operations are still needed afterwards, you create a startup script that does those and run that on the container start so that they are executed on the files of the volume.

Does your script work from the folder it currently is in? If it does, you run it from there. If it does not, you move it out of the folder permanently and run it the same way as before.

Comment: i already have a separate development image & a production image, even staging. see https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite (oops, i havent commited it yet, sorry... but i have 3 different ones) as an example which shows next.js + docker example. however, that doesn't have live reloading working in development as i have not mounted `.:/app` in the development docker compose. anyways what exactly is the solution & how do i solve it?

Comment: Can't give exact code that I can verify to work because of all the dependencies, but I added the general idea to the answer.

Comment: i updated https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite to use 3 different dockerfiles. i am not getting what you mean by adding everything to `/app`. i use `WORKDIR /app` at the start of every `FROM` so not sure how that would look like? i only asked bcz i didn't understand what you actually meant. do you mean i remove everything that does `COPY /app` or something else?

Comment: I mean that whatever you currently do in your Dockerfile that does anything related to the folder `/app` is completely meaningless (for example those `COPY` operations), since your volume mount overrides it completely on startup with the contents of your local directory.

Comment: so i did what you said & followed [this blog](https://dawchihliou.github.io/articles/the-last-dockerfile-you-need-for-nestjs) & used 1 dockerfile with 1 run.sh & 3 docker-compose.yml but i still get the same error. when i exec into that container, `MODE=development sh ./scripts/run.sh` runs fine but `sh ./scripts/run.sh` gives error as `$MODE` is used in `run.sh`. i used `command` in `docker-compose.yml` instead of `CMD` in `Dockerfile`. any ideas? code is at https://github.com/deadcoder0904/easypanel-nextjs-sqlite

Answer (score 1):

> I want hmr/live-reloading to work with remix.  [...] I need Redis which isn't directly available in Windows.

You can use Docker to only run the dependencies, and ordinary host tools for your main program.

If you run

```bash
docker-compose up -d redis
```

then *only* the Redis container will start, but not the main application.  Since you have published `ports:` in the Compose file, you can reconfigure your application to talk to `localhost:6379` as the location of the Redis server (using the first `ports:` number).

From there, if you have access to a POSIX shell, you can run the `run.dev.sh` script, or you can manually run the SQLite migrations and the main application

```bash
export DB_PATH=../../data/affiliates.dev.sqlite
pnpm db:migrate:dev  # if needed
pnpm dev
```

If you do ultimately want to deploy this in a container, it's common practice to run a separate database container rather than SQLite, and you could use a container database in combination with host code the same way as here.  It's also important to delete the `volumes:` in the Compose file so that you're using the code built into the image, both for integration testing and final deployment, and to avoid irregularities like what you describe in the question.

Comment: yes, this was one approach but i ultimately decide to just start 1 container. i'm close to solving it as i just got a poc working. can you explain why database container needs to be separate? i see many online projects like https://github.com/epicweb-dev/epic-stack & https://github.com/kentcdodds/kentcdodds.com use it in the same container. any references to read? fwiw, sqlite is more than enough for my use-case. if it ever becomes a problem, i can afford to migrate later.

Comment: i tried making my thing work but for some reason, it doesn't work. so i went with your solution only after a week of trying to make it work. i'm not sure how https://jameschambers.co.uk/nextjs-hot-reload-docker-development works which is similar to my code except i use `.sh` script that gets replaced somehow. i wanted to do automatic migrations but that gives errors plus hot-reloading didn't work. right now, i use redis in docker & everything else is simply dev mode. works best for now. i'll revisit this issue later.