# openning a text file when working on a docker container

Tags: python, linux, docker, text-files

In my code, I have a line to open a text file from a directory. When I was using jupyter notebook in Windows 10, it works perfectly.

```
a = open('C:\\users\\pym\\Desktop\\test\\Data.txt', 'r')
```

I decided to switch running my codes in Linux.
I created a directory on my host machine using `mkdir ~/notebooks`
then, I used `docker run -p 8888:8888 -v ~/notebooks:/home/jovyan jupyter/minimal-notebook` to mount the directory to the docker container directory. now everything that I do in jupyter notebook saves on that directory.

But when I try to open this file, I get the following error

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/pym/notebooks/test/Data.txt'
```

I have used the following line to read the file, and I tested that with slash, backslash, double backslash,..., but no success.

```
a = open('/home/pym/notebooks/test/Data.txt', 'r')
a = open('\home\pym\notebooks\test\Data.txt', 'r')
a = open('\\home\\pym\\notebooks\\test\\Data.txt', 'r')
```

anyone knows what is the solution?

Comment: You need to [mount a volume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container) to access the files from within the docker container.

Comment: @AnonCoward I created a directory mkdir ~/notebooks on my host machine, then I used docker run -p 8888:8888 -v ~/notebooks:/home/jovyan jupyter/minimal-notebook to mount the directory to the docker container directory. now everything that I do in jupyter notebook saves on that directory. However; it still get the same Error.

Answer (score 0):

Please open terminal in directory where text file is there. and write pwd command in terminal then enter. it returns the path directory of your text file.

Comment: thank you Zeinab. I have entered the directory address correctly.