# Generate Locust reports on a Teamcity build server

Tags: teamcity, performance-testing, locust, build-server

I have been able to successfully deploy my locust scripts to Teamcity but I can't find the reports (CSV and HTML) that I specified. I included `ls` in my command line build step and I can see that the reports are in the working directory. How do I get these reports into the artifacts tab?

My execution command looks like this:

```
locust -f public_apis/themes.py -u 50 -r 10 -t 300s --headless --print-stats --csv /reports/csv/result_for --csv-full-history --html /reports/html/docker_loadtest_result.html
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Teamcity, but your paths you're trying to save the reports to suggest Docker could be involved. If that's true, you'd have to ensure you mount a path from the host machine to a volume in Docker and then save the reports there. If you don't, they'll be inside the Docker container if they get created.

[How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container)