# Docker: Error parsing configuration files, file does not exist

Tags: docker

I am following a tutorial and using `sqlc` in my project. However, it's weird that I seem to mount an empty volume. After checking another post [mounting the host directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container), I found docker creates another empty folder, confirming that I did something wrong about it. Docker documentation doesn't help resolve this issue. Currently, my command with bash terminal:

```
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)://src -w //src kjconroy/sqlc init
docker run --rm -v $(pwd)://src -w //src kjconroy/sqlc generate
```

The first command runs successfully but creates another empty folder. The built container is running, and it's path is: `\\wsl$\docker-desktop-data\data\docker\volumes` on my Windows 10. However, the folder structure is different from the tutorial when I download the desktop docker, so I'll add extra information about how I construct the setting. The construction is using Make with docker:

```
postgres:
    docker run --name postgreslatest -p 5432:5432 -e POSTGRES_USER=root -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=secret -d postgres
createdb:
    docker exec -it postgreslatest createdb --username=root --owner=root simple_bank
dropdb:
    docker exec -it postgreslatest dropdb simple_bank
migrateup:
    migrate -path db/migration -database "postgresql://root:secret@localhost:5432/simple_bank?sslmode=disable" -verbose up
migratedown:
    migrate -path db/migration -database "postgresql://root:secret@localhost:5432/simple_bank?sslmode=disable" -verbose down

.PHONY: postgres createdb dropdb migrateup migratedown
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working. First of all, I still have no idea why bash command cannot correctly locate the `sqlc.yaml` file. However, under Windows 10 OS, I succeeded locate and generating files with the command provided by [docs](https://docs.sqlc.dev/en/latest/overview/install.html).

The command is: `docker run --rm -v "%cd%:/src" -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate` using ONLY **CMD** and the command also works combined with the MakeFile.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to replace

`docker run --rm -v $(shell pwd) -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate`

with

`docker run --rm -v $(PWD):/src -w /src kjconroy/sqlc generate`

in my make file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as well as the makefile can't work. I switch to CMD and it worked and I don't know why. Any way,use the second way in sqlc docs of docker : open a comand prompt (CMD) and type:

```
docker run --rm -v "%cd%:/src" -w /src sqlc/sqlc generate
```

also use CMD of make commands of makefile script. Good luck.