# Docker "file not found" in a volume

Tags: docker, dockerfile, docker-volume

I created a Docker container (calc:01) from the Ubuntu:22.04 base image.  The Dockerfile specifies a shell script (Docker_Entry_Point.sh) as the entry point.  When the shell script executes, it does not find a file in a volume that is specified in the run command.

Here's the Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
RUN echo $PATH
WORKDIR "/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/"
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV PATH="$PATH:/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/"

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y build-essential
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gdb
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y nasm

SHELL [ "bin/bash", "-c" ]
WORKDIR "/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/"
ENTRYPOINT ["Docker_Entry_Point.sh"]
```

Build it with:

```
docker build -t calc:01 .
```

Run it with:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/opt/P01_SH/_Library bash:latest bash -c "ls /opt/P01_SH/_Library"
```

Where the ls command lists the contents of the parent folder /opt/P01_SH, not the _Library subfolder.

That creates an empty subfolder by the same names under the working directory $(pwd), which is /opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles.

Finally:

```
docker run -v $(pwd):/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles -it  calc:01
```

That command calls the entrypoint shell script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Compile Object Files"
source /opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/_Library
ls -l
source /opt/P01_SH/_Library
ls -l
gcc -ggdb -shared -fPIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -ldl -lc -o Memory_Map_File.o Memory_Map_File.c
```

When I run the file with run -v $(pwd):/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles -it  calc:01 I get "file not found" as shown here:

```
run -v $(pwd):/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles -it  calc:01
```

The shell script is called and produces this output:

Compile Object Files

```
/opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/Docker_Entry_Point.sh: line 4: source:    /opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/_Library: is a directory

[ The  two -ls commands show the listing for the parent directory /opt/P01_SH/Dockerfiles/ instead of the _Library subfolder here ]

cc1: fatal error: Memory_Map_File.c: No such file or directory 

compilation terminated.
```

So the error is:  Memory_Map_File.c: No such file or directory.  But that file does exist in the filesystem folder /opt/P01_SH/_Library.

I also tried creating a named volume and using that in place of $(pwd) but still the same problem.

I read all 27 of the answers at [How to mount a host directory in a Docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container), and tried some variations, but I didn't find an answer to my question.

At https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/ it says, "Volumes are the preferred mechanism for persisting data generated by and used by Docker containers" but then it goes on to show the same syntax using -mount or -v that is used in https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/, so I'm not clear on how to distinguish volumes from bind mounts.  They both start with -mount or -v at the command line.

I've only been working with Docker for a few days.  Volumes are complex and there appear to be several different ways to do it.   My understanding is that all methods should make files on the host file system accessible to the container.

Thanks for any help on how to correct this.

Comment: This setup is recompiling the application every single time you start the container.  Is that really what you intend?  I would not generally recommend injecting the code you're trying to run via a volume; instead, `COPY` it into the image and `RUN` a build command.

Comment: I haven't found how I can use COPY to copy a complete installation of GCC, GDB, NASM.  All examples I have seen show using it to copy just a single file with an absolute path.  How can it be used to copy software installed in a previous layer?  Going forward I will want to use a layered approach, but I'm very new to Docker and I'm mainly interested in getting it to work (e.g. my question above).  Then I can approach layering when I know how to copy software installed in a previous layer.

Comment: One thing I'm noticing is that you're using the `gcc -shared -fPIC` options, which normally would create a C shared library (`*.so` file); not something that's directly runnable on its own.  A container normally wraps a _process_, not just a library; what do you hope the main process in the container will be?

Comment: The main program is a NASM program that links in several utility programs as object files written in C.

Comment: ...so the image is just a collection of build tools; the final output of this build-then-run-a-container sequence you hope to be a binary, that won't itself run in a container?

Comment: No. the image calls a shell script as its entry point, and that shell script initiates the process that runs in the container.  The container is not just a collection of build tools.  Right now my only issue is the one described in my question above.  I'm considering whether Docker Compose would be better because its syntax for volumes is very clean, and Compose is a one-step process.

Comment: With that setup, I'd expect you to `RUN` the build sequence in the Dockerfile, and set the default image `CMD` to be to run the compiled application.  You wouldn't need volumes or bind mounts at all.  A multi-stage build would be nice but isn't required for a first pass.

Comment: How does my container use files from the host filesystem without volumes or bind mounts?