Apache druid cant find jvm.config
I am trying to run apache druid through docker like this
docker pull apache/druid:24.0.0
docker run -p 8888:8888 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 8090:8090 --name druid apache/druid:24.0.0

But I am receiving this error:
cat: can't open '/tmp/conf/druid/cluster/misc//jvm.config': No such file or directory

What is this file? How to fix this issue?

This seems like a good answer to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container
