How to copy files in docker container to local?
I have a program which creates files and i need to create these files to user into a project-folder outside of container. When im using docker container these files creates inside of container, but i need to share them to users outside of container to local of my folder with a project.
i saw docker cp but im need for an automatically copying solution.

You could mount a directory into the container such that when the container writes to those files inside. They are also visible outside. https://docs.docker.com/engine/storage/volumes/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-a-host-directory-in-a-docker-container

If a principal part of your application involves writing local files, or knowing who the local user is, it may be much easier to run directly on the host: containers don't have direct access to the user's home directory or any knowledge of who the host user might be.

You can achieve by docker volume & bind mount, where you will be able to bind a host volume to container volume. You need to make sure the permission while doing volume bind is correct. You can refer to the following document:

https://docs.docker.com/engine/storage/volumes/ -as in the comment and
https://docs.docker.com/engine/storage/bind-mounts/


Thanks you guys for helps!
my solution:
docker run -v $(pwd)/result_folder:/<project_folder>/result_folder <container_name>

